# How is this swap type expression working?

Tags: python, variables, boolean, swap

I have been experimenting with python. I found the swapping method for variables:

```
var1, var2 = var2, var3
```

I thought to use the same method with comparison (`==`), but the output is not satisfying.

```
>>> foo = 2
>>> bar = 3
>>> foo, bar == bar, foo
(2, True, 2)
>>>
```

I thought it would give simply `False`. Reason:

foo is not equal to bar and bar is not equal to foo

[image]

I made some more tests:

```
>>> foo = 2
>>> bar = 3
>>> foobar = 4
>>> foo, bar, foobar == foobar, foo, bar
(2, 3, True, 2, 3)
>>>
```

The result is still sort of same and I expected it to give `False`. Reason:

[image]

---

How is this working?

Comment: operator precedence for equality isn't the same as the one for assignment.

Comment: Assignment does some magic called tuple unpacking that makes it work the way you see in `a, b = b, c`. Equality has no equivalent magic, so in addition to the fact that `a, b == b, c` is parsed as the tuple `(a, (b == b), c)`, even if it parsed the way you imagined with the groups binding more tightly, it would check if the tuple `(a, b)` is equal to the tuple `(b, c)` (which unless `a==b==c` is trivially false)

Comment: I'm not sure why all the downvotes..?  This is a very clear disposition of the problem the OP is having, it has a MCVE -- and even diagrams ;-)  What more could one want from a question?

Comment: @thebjorn A fundamental misunderstanding of a foundational system like this leads many people to downvote for not enough research effort, but I don't see an easy way to look up how this works if I weren't experienced enough to see the patterns myself. I upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with operator precedence, just like

```
2 + 3 * 4 == 14
```

because it is the same as (because `*` has higher precedence than `+`)

```
2 + (3 * 4)
```

the expression

```
var1, var2 = var2, var3
```

is the same as (because the comma-operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator):

```
(var1, var2) = (var2, var3)
```

and

```
var1, var2 == var2, var3
```

is the same as (because the `==` operator has higher precedence than the comma-operator)

```
var1, (var2 == var2), var3
```

The relevant part of the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

The desired result, i.e. an expression that yields

```
(a==c), (b==d)
```

from

```
a, b ... c, d
```

is slightly more complicated in the general case. You can of course just write `(a==c), (b==d)` or even `a==c, b==d`, but @AdamSmith's suggestion will work for any number of parameters (and you don't need to extract the tuple elements):

```
all(x==y for x,y in zip([a, b], [c, d]))
```

Comment: Note that even if the operator precedence was correct, `(a, b) == (c, d)` will never give `(a==c), (b==d)` as the OP seems to want (but rather `(a==c) and (b==d)`)

Comment: May be worth including something like `all(a==b for a,b in zip([foo, bar, foobar], [foobar, foo, bar]))` as an alternative syntax for the above